# How to fire an event after pressing the enter key with text box value?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I want to add enter key press event for a kendo textbox.

I used following line of code.

it prevent typing in text box. How can I do that?

Comment: You forgot to add the line of code you've mentioned...

Comment: <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (keypress)="$event.keyCode === 13 && onSearchButtonClick()"/>

Answer (score 0):

```js
function textChangedVal() {
    var textboxIDVa = document.getElementById("textboxID");
    var sv = textboxIDVa.value;

    var spanIDVa = document.getElementById("spanID");
    spanIDVa.innerText = "The text box contains: " + sv;

}
```

```html
<textarea id="textboxID" type="text" onkeypress="textChangedVal(event)"></textarea><br>
<span id="spanID"></span>
```